# Ksoap response parsing error on Vector

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I've a soap webservice and an android application for invoke service. App always works, but after last webservice update, something gone wrong. The update of webservice was made only to delete some unused service. Other code wasn't modified.
My android application use an AsyncTask to call service and get back result:

```
public class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Vector<SoapObject>> {
private static String METHOD_NAME = "getData";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.com/getData";
private static String URL = "http://arduino-data-server.appspot.com/dataserver";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com/";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected Vector<SoapObject> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Vector<SoapObject> result = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

but i obtain the sequent error:

```
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at com.example.soapclient.DownloadDataTask.doInBackground(DownloadDataTask.java:49)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at com.example.soapclient.DownloadDataTask.doInBackground(DownloadDataTask.java:1)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-11 18:36:25.063: E/AndroidRuntime(9250):     ... 4 more
```

where line 49 is the line where i invoke getResult() method.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is clear:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject 
cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
```

In this line, you can not cast the result SoapObject to Vector:

```
Vector<SoapObject> result = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();
```

Try this:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```